# STARTTLS error when sending alerts from Cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager, google-workspace

I'm trying to adjust alerts using Cloudera's Alert publisher (v. 5.14). Here are my alert publisher's settings from Cloudera's UI:

```
 - Enable Email Alerts: true
 - Mail Server Protocol: smtp
 - Mail Server Hostname: smtp.gmail.com
 - Mail Server Username: sender@hadoop-cluster.org
 - Mail From Address: sender@hadoop-cluster.org
 - Mail Message Recipients: recipient@gmail.com
 - Mail Server TCP Port: 587
```

Any others configs I left by default. Sender's and recipient's emails was obfuscated in this snippet but I can say that "hadoop-cluster.org" is a domain which have a GSuite record so SMTP configs of hadoop-cluster.org should be similar to GMail configs.

When I've applied these settings and restart Cloudera management service I've tried to send test alert. In alert publister's logs I'm catching the following exception:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p10*****.47 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:355)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:344)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer.process(MailProducer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)
```

What I'm doing wrong? I've searched the answer on Cloudera's community forums but didn't found any useful advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Must issue a STARTTLS command**

Enable TLS security by configuring **Mail Server Protocol: smtps**

Restart cloudera management service and trigger a test email. Don't need to explicitly specify tls port. It will use port 587 by default.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me but with 465 port instead of 587. If I still using 587, I'm getting such error in Cloudera logs: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` ("Use ... or port 587 if your client begins with plain text before issuing the STARTTLS command." as I've red in the smtp guide). **I'll edit the answer**.